Easiest way to gather users' step (health) data from Apple Watch to web service
I work in healthcare research. We have a study going on that uses Garmin devices to track subjects' total steps during the day. It was pretty simple for us to implement by creating a REST endpoint in AWS and using Garmin APIs to register a device and have data pushed to that endpoint.
The question now is how easy would it be to extend this to other devices, in particular the Apple Watch. It seems that we could develop a simple app for the subject to run on their Watch that would push the data. But is there a route that doesn't involve creating a mobile app? I was thinking the Google Fit app and Fit REST API, but I see there is some kind of transition going on from the Fit REST api to Health Connect.
Just looking for some pointers on apps/services to investigate. A key consideration here is that it needs to be very easy for the subjects to setup on their devices.
Thanks
-Squid

Going to vote to close this as it's asking for services recommendations. That being said, you may have interest in MyDataHelps. Full disclosure: I work for the vendor.
